# Display required reputation to attempt a badge?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, badges

Should badges associated with tasks that are only available beyond certain reputation-based privilege milestones indicate this next to the badge icon? Something like this:
[image: badge suggestion]

EDIT: To clarify, this would always be the minimum reputation required to earn the badge in question at least once. As this badge states you must complete one review task (in one category) to earn this badge once, and the first review privileges become available at 500 reputation, that is the value that would be shown next to the badge icon.

EDIT #2: It was pointed out in the comments below that the first review task available is at 1 reputation. This highlights my point. We need more information about which badges are accessible when.

Comment: That may be the case, but as this badge is awarded once per review task, this is the **minimum reputation required** to earn this badge.

Comment: Do we really need this?  Can users not figure this out easily enough on their own if they really need to?

Comment: I edited my post to remove the questions tag, that was a mistake on my part. I will edit again to include the above mentioned detail in my post.

Comment: @Servy It's not difficult to figure this out, true, but it's more **convenient** to have all the information located in one central location.

Comment: We'll see if people really want this feature based on the voting.

Comment: I'm fine with this.  It makes the badge gamification aspect more visible.

Comment: I like this idea, as it opens new users up to see privileges which they may not have been aware of existing. Gamify++;

Comment: Note that for the given example badge, the stated minimum is **wrong**, or at least incomplete and misleading. You can get Custodian in at least one queue at 1 rep: accept or reject a suggested edit to one of your own posts.

Comment: Ah my apologies, I guess that hasn't come up for me yet. However, **this highlights my exact point**: the minimum reputation needed to earn a badge should be shown near each badge.

Comment: I don't think this would be a good idea. And aside from that it wouldn't even work. Not every badge depends on the user having some privilege which they get at x reputation. And what about badges like legendary? Would the reputation requirement for that be 30k? Doesn't make much sense in my opinion.

Comment: That's why I qualified my request with: associated with tasks only available beyond a certain reputation level.

Comment: Another way to go about this, **perhaps in a less intrusive way** for those who may not want the screen real estate taken up, would be to modify the hover tooltip to display the reputation requirement (if applicable) instead of the badge description.